# Wrong count for new comment responses in profile window

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

Today when I logged onto my SO account (into my profile) I saw `61` new comment responses alert in blue but not a single one in the upper right notification area. When I clicked on the list no new responses was added... Well I taught occasional bug and left it be ... When I log later today again I saw the same issue with `221` new comment responses... That is possibly not a coincidence hence this (bug report)

[image: screenshot]

it is not a big deal but might causing other problems on the site side which I have no insight to so it might be worth looking if persist.

In case it is browser related I am using **Opera**:

```
Version information

    Version:    45.0.2552.812 (PGO) - Opera is up to date
    Update stream:  Stable
    System: Windows 7 64-bit

Browser identification

    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.812
```

Comment: When you click on "Responses", are you on the "comment" sub tab, or "all"? If "all", you'll likely see a lot of revisions from "Community" as they change links for HTTPS.

Comment: @Kendra it is on `comments` sub tab but there are no new messages highlighted and the order is consistent with real messages. The number of new responses increased to `383` by now. but if the addressing is changing to https as you suggested then I just have to wait ...

Comment: @Kendra looks like the problem has stopped